# Count in a series of 9 digits - javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how do you count an array with 9 being the highest digit?

Like so:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var i =0
while (i++ <= 300 ) 
 document.body.innerHTML += (((i-1)%9 )+ 1);
```

Use the % operator. You will need to take 1 away and add to it to get 1-9 instead of 0-8

Assuming a max of 300 ( thought I read 300 but can't see it now)